# Jquery Click Variable Loop

Tags: jquery, variables, loops, dynamic, click

I am working on getting assigning a dynamic variable within Jquery in which the buttons could change to be more or less so I figured a loop would be best. (that rimes oo god it's gotten to be that fun).  So here is the break down in which I can not seem to get to figured out.

```
$(".acc_trigger").each(function(j) {

    $("#accord" + j).click(function() {
        $(".selectedimg").hide('drop', { direction: 'down' }, 1000);
        $(".selectedimg").removeClass("selectedimg");

        $("#accordimg"+ j ).addClass("selectedimg");
        $("#accordimg"+ j ).show('drop', { direction: 'up' }, 1000);

  });
});
```

For each class which are buttons add a click in which the id has a number to the end of it which removes the class selected but then replaces with the same number used in the id above.  I can't get this to work and have thought about using loops but when I do it goes the same number of times the loop is for.  I'm trying to just create a number of click functions that allows for the variable to be dynamic to make it so I can have more or less buttons.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should be able to use jQuery's live function to do this without having to use loops or anything.

```
$('.CssClassThatAllYourButtonsShare').live('click', function() {
        $(".selectedimg").hide('drop', { direction: 'down' }, 1000);
        $(".selectedimg").removeClass("selectedimg");

        //Extract the number from the current ID
        var j = $(this).attr('id').match(/\d+$/);

        $("#accordimg"+ j).addClass("selectedimg");
        $("#accordimg"+ j).show('drop', { direction: 'up' }, 1000);
});
```

Documentation on Live: http://api.jquery.com/live/

> Description: Attach a handler to the
>   event for all elements which match the
>   current selector, now and in the
>   future.

Comment: Where do you get the value for the variable `j`?

Comment: How is j geting set in your example?

Comment: I'm sorry j is a number that pertains to a button on the accordion and image that the accordion button goes with.  So I only want the image that corresponds to the button.  Does this make sense?

Comment: $("#accord" + 1) with  $("#accordimg"+ 1 ) I am trying to loop through and make numerous clicks that correspond with 1 to 1 and 2 to 2 depending on the amount of buttons.

Comment: @Dan - Got it when I re-read your question. See my updated answer.

Comment: Need a bit of a change.  There is three id's assigned to the class so it loops three times.  I'm trying to get it to select the one id.  That is why I was looping through it to make loop through each individual id.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work just fine, if the options for the `show` and `hide` works.

I tested your code, only with the options for the `show` and `hide` reduced (as I don't know what plugin you use for that custom easing), and it works just fine:

http://jsfiddle.net/EJyn5/

#### Edit:

Judging by your comment to Brandons answer; perhaps you are starting your elements with index 1 instead of index 0?

Comment: Well I'm trying to not have it loop through three times and just onece.  I'm trying to spin off make three separate click functions that will have a their numbers differ by one starting at 0.  When adding a loop you make it execute the number of times the loop is made.

Comment: @Dan: The code only binds one event to one element in each iteration, so you don't get multiple events. Perhaps there is something wrong with your markup, so that the elements are nested inside each other instead of placed after each other, then the click event would bubble up through the elements.

Comment: you are right.  I had to unbind and rebind.  Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and it works fine, here's the example I made. (minus your plugin)

http://jsfiddle.net/5tLZk/3/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid the loop, this should work (assuming that the .img elements are between the .acc_trigger elements).

```
<div class="acc_trigger" id="accord0">0</div>
<div class="img" id="accordimg0">0</div>
<div class="acc_trigger" id="accord1">1</div>
<div class="img" id="accordimg1">1</div>
<div class="acc_trigger" id="accord2">2</div>
<div class="img" id="accordimg2">2</div>

$(".acc_trigger").click(function() {
    $(".selectedimg").hide(1000);
    $(".selectedimg").removeClass("selectedimg");

    $(this).next(".img").addClass("selectedimg");
    $(this).next(".img").show(1000);
});
```

You can try it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/EJyn5/.